# flutter_bloc(did not work second time uses emit)

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

So, I was working with flutter framework for create a news app project. News come from an API who gives 1st time top ids then gives details base on ids. When I call for id its works its emited by bloc  and if I tried to display on my emulator its works but when I tried for details, details receives from API but don't emitted that's why I cant avail to show on screen news details.
For 2nd time dos not find any state

## **1. The error is pointing from 2nd emit which is on 2nd event.**

## **And 2nd/inner BlocBuilder**

**bloc file:**

```
import 'package:news_flutter_bloc/data/model/item_model.dart';
import 'stories_event.dart';
import 'stories_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import '../data/api/news_api_provider.dart';
class StoriesBloc extends Bloc\<StoriesEvent, StoriesState\> {
final NewsApiProvider \_newsApiProvider = NewsApiProvider();
StoriesBloc() : super(StoriesInitialState()) {
    on<StoriesTopIdsEvent>((event, emit) async {
      try {
        List ids = await _newsApiProvider.fetchTopIds();
        emit(StoriesTopIdsState(ids));
      } catch (ex) {
        emit(StoriesErrorState(ex.toString()));
      }
    });
    on<StoriesItemsEvent>((event, emit) async {
      try {
        ItemModel items =
            (await _newsApiProvider.fetchItems(event.id));
        emit(StoriesItemsState(items));
    
      } catch (ex) {
        emit(StoriesErrorState(ex.toString()));
      }
    });
}
}
```

**Event call file**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:news_flutter_bloc/blocs/stories_bloc.dart';
import 'package:news_flutter_bloc/blocs/stories_event.dart';
import 'package:news_flutter_bloc/blocs/stories_state.dart';
import 'package:news_flutter_bloc/data/model/item_model.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const HomeScreen({super.key});

@override
State\<HomeScreen\> createState() =\> \_HomeScreenState();
}

class \_HomeScreenState extends State\<HomeScreen\> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
BlocProvider.of\<StoriesBloc\>(context).add(StoriesTopIdsEvent());
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: const Text(
"Today's News",
style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 25,
fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
),
),
centerTitle: true,
),
body: SafeArea(
child: BlocBuilder\<StoriesBloc, StoriesState\>(
builder: (context, state) {
if (state is StoriesInitialState) {
return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
}
if (state is StoriesTopIdsState) {
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: state.ids.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
int id = state.ids\[index\];
BlocProvider.of\<StoriesBloc\>(context).add(
StoriesItemsEvent(id));

                    return BlocBuilder<StoriesBloc, StoriesState>(
                      builder: (context, state) {
    
                        if(state is StoriesItemsState) {
                          ItemModel item = state.items;
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              ListTile(
                                title: Text(item.title.toString()),
                              ),
                              Divider(
                                height: 5.0,
                                thickness: 5.0,
                                color: Colors.deepPurple.shade100,
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                        else if(state is StoriesErrorState){
                          return Text(state.error);
                        }
                        return const Center(child: Text("2nd error"));
                      },
                    );
                  });
            }else {
              return const Center(child: Text('1st error'));
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );

}
```

Comment: Use initState or BlocListener to call events, not in build method which can be called without you knowing and therefore cause some weird problems.

Comment: I cant understand please. Give me more explanation